# Default working directory for JUnit test - how can we define it consistently in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, directory

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html),

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative
>   pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named
>   by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in
>   which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

So, according to it, if I run a JUnit class from the popup menu, choosing JUnit test, the current folder should be the folder in which the test class lies.

But really it takes the Default Working Directory from the page of Run Configurations - Environment page for the last Run Configuration used. So, if the test uses files with relative paths, mostly it cannot be launched correctly from the popup menu.

Even if I create a Run Configuration for the JUnit test class, yes, it will automatically set its Default Working Directory (On Run Configurations - Environment page) to the folder where the test file is. But still, used through popup menu, it again takes the Default Working Directory from the last Run Configuration used.

How can I set default directory or Eclipse somehow so, that I will can launch my test classes with the current folder according to documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide an example of what you try to do but I guess you try to load some file which you need in your test. If thats the case you should better change the way you load the file.

[`YourTestClass.class.getResource("filename")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or[`YourTestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("filename")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) is what you should use. It looks up a file relative to `YourTestClass`.

Comment: This approach is also the right one if you use some build tool like maven/gradle, as you will be able to place the file somewhere in src/test/resources and calling it with the right path will just always work...

Comment: Thank you for answer and edition, but I am really interested in how can we work with the default dir. Notice, I am not looking for Java solution. I am looking for Java+Eclipse solution. Eclipse and Java both support default folder in some way. I am trying to do it in some useful way.

Comment: BTW, that another way through class.getResource() or .class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation(), widely presented on the SO, works correctly only out of plugins or any other structures with additional classloaders.